# Angular 2+ set standard Form field appearance value

Tags: angular, default, appearance, form-fields

Working actually on form fields, I'm only using an outline appearance for my inputs (see more [here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants)).

Not wanting to copy `appearance=outline` everywhere on each form, I wanted to know if there was a way to set the standard value of the appearance on outline.

I've found out in the API that there is a `MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` ([link](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#constants)). But I don't know how to use it and didn't found much documentation on it.

---

Or maybe should I just stick with a basic `appearance="{{defaultAppearance}}"` 
on each form field and set a global variable, but I still have to duplicate this code everywhere (but it still allows me change the style easily whenever I want to)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got the answer [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12765).

add this:

```
{ provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'outline' }}
```

in the providers of @ngModule.

Comment: Note: I found that you have to restart your locally running app to see these changes, they don't come through with hot reload.

Comment: I added this to my AppModule class and also had to put this at the top of the file: import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';